# How can I dynamically set a System property on the JVM, after it has started, without modifying my program's code?

Tags: java, jvm, jmx

I would like to be able to change a system property while a java application is running inside an application server. I know that this can be done with `java.lang.System.setProperty` or by adding the `-DpropertyName=value` as a JVM flag.

But I want to do this at runtime and without modifying the application code.

Is there a tool that can change system properties in the JVM at runtime without having to update the application-code ( e.g. just by attaching a tool the running process or by using JMX ) ?

Comment: Doesn't seem so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469774/how-to-change-java-properties-at-runtime

Comment: Seeing the link that @shmosel provided, the least dirty thing you can do is to store your properties in an external file that your program reads  actively when appropriate.

Comment: @GyroGearloose This requires updating the application code, which is not an option as noted on my question.

Comment: The update of the code would be necessary only once, from then on the code could check on the property-file all for itself. But if your'e not the owner of the code, then your out of luck and options. But if so, this is someone else's problem, not yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Java properties at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469774/how-to-change-java-properties-at-runtime)

Comment: This is a duplicate question, please close it

Comment: @GyroGearloose "But if your'e not the owner of the code, then your out of luck and options". Not really. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to attach an agent that calls `System.setProperty` to a running application.
**Note:** this does not require modifying application code.

Here is the agent code:

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;

public class SetProperty {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = SetProperty.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
        if (args.length < 2 || !url.startsWith("file:")) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java -jar setproperty.jar pid property=value");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(args[0]);
        try {
            int startIndex = "\\".equals(System.getProperty("file.separator")) ? 6 : 5;
            vm.loadAgent(url.substring(startIndex), args[1]);
        } finally {
            vm.detach();
        }
    }

    public static void agentmain(String args) {
        int eq = args.indexOf('=');
        System.setProperty(args.substring(0, eq), args.substring(eq + 1));
    }
}
```

1. Compile the source code:

```
javac -source 8 -target 8 SetProperty.java
```

2. Create `MANIFEST.MF` file with the following contents:

```
Main-Class: SetProperty
Agent-Class: SetProperty
```

3. Build .jar file from the compiled sources and the manifest:

```
jar cfm setproperty.jar MANIFEST.MF SetProperty.class
```

4. Launch the agent passing the target process ID and the property to set (JDK 9+):

```
java -jar setproperty.jar 1234 MyProperty=SomeValue
```

If you are using JDK 8, you'll need to add `tools.jar` to the class path:

```
java -cp setproperty.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar SetProperty 1234 MyProperty=SomeValue
```

I prepared [setproperty.jar](https://profiler.tools/misc/setproperty.jar) so you can skip steps 1-3 and proceed directly to the final command.

Comment: Nice! This elegant solution is what I was looking for. After some research I was also ready to post a similar answer but I missed the`SetProperty.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()` to get the jar path.

Comment: I think a drawback is that you cannot easily unload the agent, so next time you need to change a system property value you will need to load a second agent instance e.t.c. Perhaps an improvement could be that the agent accepts a `system-properties-overrides` .properties file as an option , watches it for changes and updates the corresponding system properties accordingly.

Comment: On my system I can't find neither tools.jar nor can I import VirtualMachine via eclipse ... . Still I can compile and run your example on the command line. Looks this is a very different problem local to my machine. Thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: @MarinosAn There is no problem in setting multiple properties. You *can* attach the same agent as many times as needed. It will be loaded only once, but `agentmain` will execute each time with new arguments.

Comment: Instead of calling `toString()` on a `URL` and doing this “magic” `int startIndex = "\\".equals(System.getProperty("file.separator")) ? 6 : 5;` … `url.substring(startIndex)` I’d rather convert the `URL` to a file using `Paths.get(url.toURI()).toString()` which is simpler and more reliable. It’s also worth noting that there are plans to disable dynamic agent loading by default, so for future Java versions, dynamic attach has to be enabled via the command line option `-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading` at startup.